# Jest - how can i export test documentation in order to share test with coworkers?

Tags: jestjs, documentation

My Jest - Puppeteer testsuite has more than 100 functional tests.
My coworker is asking me "what does your testsuite do?"
i don't wont to create external documentation of my documented tests,
i would like to generate an html file containing my already documented test informations.

e.g.

```
test("if it raining, umbrella must to be opened", async() => {
  /**
   * this test ask user if the umbrella is opened. if opened test pass.
   */
  // some code
})
```

i would like to obtain documentation.html containing

```
<h1>test documentation</h1>
<ul>
<li>
test1 : if it raining, umbrella must to be opened
this test ask user if the umbrella is opened. if opened test pass.
</li>
</ul>
```

i already have test report, but this is a bit different, i don't want to share test results, i want to share what the testsuite is doing.

i searched for "jest export documentation" or similar. Any suggestion?

thanks

Comment: I don't think this can be called documentation, that's the reason you can't find anything. Basically you need the information on registered tests. This can be achieved with test reporter. Usually an answer to such coworker's question would be a link to CI where a report in human readable form is available. I don't think that red and green colors affect the usefulness of the output. But in case existing HTML reporters don't suit you, you can fork or create a custom one that deliberately ignores the information on passed/failed tests and only outputs their names.

Comment: i think using test results reporting is a workaround